# How can I get live feedback from my backend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using a POST jQuery request on the client side. This post request starts a function. When the function is finished (putting some stuff in a mongodb) I want that the client updates the data on the website without the user needing to refresh.

Can you guys give me any ideas how to do that? I just don't even know how to approach it or how to Google it :/

My stack is: Nodejs, Express, EJS, MongoDB and jQuery

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you showed us your client-side code. But what you want is called AJAX, which you can use to communicate between the your client and server apps. You can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: @BThuy The client side is just a simple jQuery ajax post with preventDefault so that the client not refresh after posting. So I am already using AJAX.

I just don't know how could I use AJAX to wait for the backend to be finished.

Comment: You need to send that data back to the client using res.json and then add it to the DOM using JS or jQuery which ever you want to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to construct an AJAX request, which you already have
- Then inside your backend when your mentioned function finishes processing the clients request and writing it to the database you need to send it back to the client using res.json

  ```
  router.post('/whatever_endpoint_you_are_using', function(req, res, next) {
    // code for processing the response & writing stuff to the database
    // then send the data back to the client
      res.json({"data": your_data});   
  });
  ```
- Then you can access this data on the client, inside of the success callback of your AJAX request

  ```
  success: function(response){
     console.log(response.data) // your_data
  }
  ```
- Lastly, you can use JS or jQuery to add this data to the DOM (you mentioned you're using jQuery so here's a jQuery example)

  ```
  $('#data_container').append('<p>'+response.data+'</p>')

  // or something similar I don't know how your page is structured
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I still not understand how exactly would I send the data back to the client? Which command do I use for that?